# js passing two functions to a method

Tags: javascript, syntax

Which is the correct syntax to pass two or more functions to a method for example

`setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);`
is the following correct?

`setInterval("pushmarkers();clearOverlays();loadmarkers();",5000);`

Comment: never pass strings to `setInterval`, pass functions instead :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap them in another function:

```
setInterval(function() {
  pushmarkers();
  clearOverlays();
  loadmarkers();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not pass strings to `setInterval`, this uses `eval` (which is evil).

You can pass an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function () {
    pushmarkers();
    clearOverlays();
    loadmarkers();
}, 5000);
```

Or a named function:

```
var functionForSetInterval = function () {
    pushmarkers();
    clearOverlays();
    loadmarkers();
};

setInterval(functionForSetInterval, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither is good practice because you are giving `setInterval` strings, not references to functions.

You need to give setInterval a function, and you can easily make a function that calls other functions (wrap them in a function):

```
setInterval(function(){ pushmarkers(); clearOverlays(); loadmarkers(); }, 5000);
```

or

```
function multifunction(){
    pushmarkers();
    clearOverlays();
    loadmarkers();
}

setInterval(multifunction, 5000);
```